# GUI to admin the appengine through remote api appart of _ah/admin

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, remoteapi

I have seen that there is a programatic interface called remote api to manage the appengine instances. It's weird to me that no one developed a tool to access it from your desktop (I'm thinking on a swing app as JConsole).

Do you know any or similars?

What I want to acheive is to execute GSQL as the admin console in production.

Comment: all remote_api is are api proxies that forward the rpcs to an appengine app. if there were a gui, it wouldn't look anymore like a terminal or python interpreter. I don't know how it would work in java(jython probably) but in python it's pretty trivial to write a script to drop you into the interpreter with everything already to go.

Answer (score 0):

`google/appengine/tools/remote_api_shell.py` in the app engine SDK does exactly what tom describes. it's a command line python shell that imports the app engine libraries, connects to your app, and lets you use the datastore, memcache, and other APIs against that app.

if you want a GUI instead, here's a candidate:
http://code.google.com/p/gae-datastore-backup-utility/

it'd also be straightforward to write your own, using remote_api.